# How to put text in a circle in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to display a numerical text in a circle. I tried the following, but it looks fuzzy

```
Container(child: Text(len),
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  shape: BoxShape.circle,
  border: Border.all(width: 2)))
```

This is how it looks . BTW it's number *2* in a circle.

[image]

Comment: add padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0) in container.

Answer (score 5):

```
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 20,
  child: Text('$value'),
),
```

Comment: you can also use your code and give `fontSize` to the text.

Answer (score 1):

If you want add spacing between the border and the Edge of the border, you can either add a `Padding` with `EdgeInsets` or reduce the `fontSize` of the `Text`

[Visit the Flutter Docs for more information and an example.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container/alignment.html)

Comment: Yes @Rohan that is exactly what I just realised. `Padding` works.
I tried reducing `fontSize` of text: that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
Container(
width:40.0,
height:40.0,
child: Center(child:Text(len)),
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  shape: BoxShape.circle,
  border: Border.all(width: 2))),
```

Comment: yes padding  will work , this is another way !

Comment: Oh ok, so you are increasing the size of container and adjusting font size so that there is padding implicitly. It should work, but padding is neater.

Comment: no I am using `Center` widget not adjusting font size.

Imagine you want to center the text in 400.0 height container ? what would you do ? padding of 390.0 ??

Comment: Dear Moaid, `Center` will not solve the issue I am speaking of. Either `padding` or `width` are needed. I am not guessing, I just tried it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is somewhat obvious. Add this property to container `padding: EdgeInsets.all(5)`